# Set button listener in dialog

Tags: android

I'm creating a dialog like this:

```
    private void MyDialogFragment() {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mydialog, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setView(promptView);        

            final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);
            ...
```

And after that I want to set the OnCheckedChangeListener:

```
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                ...
            }
        });
```

But whenever I try to show the dialog, it crashes my app. The log says:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
```

So I'm guessing the radiogroup isn't created yet when I'm trying to set the listener. But how do I set it then?

Comment: call `findViewById` upone `promptView`. `final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) promptView.findViewById(R.id.rg);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);
```

with

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) promptView.findViewById(R.id.rg);
```